# When to use Selector(Reselect) with react redux

Tags: redux, react-redux, reselect

I have particular state object which consist of state object which looks like this.

```
{
 cards:[
      {
     id:'card01',
     title:"My card 01",
     category:[
          { 
           id:1,
           name:'cat1',
           tags:[{id:11,name:'tag1'}]
          },
          { 
           id:2,
           name:'cat2',
           tags:[{id:11,name:'tag1'}]
          }
      ]
    },
    {
     id:'card01',
     title:"My card 02",
     category:[
          { 
           id:11,
           name:'cat11',
           tags:[{id:111,name:'tag11'}]
          },
          { 
           id:22,
           name:'cat22',
           tags:[{id:111,name:'tag22'}]
          }
      ]
    }
  ] 
}
```

This particular object is fetched from the backend and it is kept in the store. I need to filter out the categories when ever the user selects a card (when a card is selected it returns of gets the card id). and i need to display the category in a different component with the tags inside the category. Do i need to use reselect for this is there any advantage of using it?. I need to to do this filtration on the data in my store.

Comment: My approach would have been to maintain selected id in different redux state i.e `selectedId:[]`
and filter that data based on `selectedId`